# Two ways of running a command checked with if

Tags: bash, subshell

Both of these work.  The first is shorter, but I'm guessing the second is safer or better - running the command inside $()

If so, could someone explain why the second is safer, better, etc.

`if my_function "something" ; then ...`

`if $(my_function "something"); then ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is usually what you want. The first one executes the function, checks its exit status, and runs the `then` section if the status indicates the function succeeds.

The second (with `$( )`) runs the function, captures whatever your function prints to stdout, and then tries to execute that output as another command. If it doesn't output anything, nothing gets run, so the `then` section gets executed if your function succeeds (just like the first version). On the other hand, if it does output anything, that gets run as another command, and the `then` section gets run if *that* succeeds. If what it printed wasn't a valid command, that counts as failure.

So, the question is, does your function print a command you want executed? If so, use the second form. It not, use the first.

Comment: thank you.  i just figured out that the second is not returning the exit status so not working as the first one does